# Java Buffered writer and file writer not writing to file

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I am experimenting with java by building a commandline game. I want to save user progress to a file , and am using buffered writer as shown below but it does not write to file.What might be the issue?

//new added Player class

```
public class Player {
   public static String name="";
   public static int money=0;
   public static int level=1;
   public static int dragons=1;
   public static String difficulty="beginner";
   public static String mode="campaign";
   public static int numberofFights=0;
   public static int fightswon=0;
   public static int fightslost=0;
```

}

```
public void savePlayer() {
    System.out.println("Type 'save' to save game progress");
    if (scanner.nextLine().equals("save")) {
        try (BufferedWriter Bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("player.txt",true));) {
            System.out.println("Saving...");    // this is trped out as expected
            Bw.write(Player.name);
            Bw.newLine();
            Bw.write("" + Player.money);
            Bw.newLine();
            Bw.write("" + Player.level);
            Bw.newLine();
            Bw.write("" + Player.dragons);
            Bw.newLine();
            Bw.write(Player.difficulty);
            Bw.newLine();
            Bw.write(Player.mode);
            Bw.newLine();
            Bw.write("" + Player.numberofFights);
            Bw.newLine();
            Bw.write("" + Player.fightswon);
            Bw.newLine();
            Bw.write("" + Player.fightslost);
            Bw.newLine();
            Bw.flush();
            saveIsland();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong input please Try again");
        promptEnterKey();
        savePlayer();
    }

}
public void saveIsland() {
    try (BufferedWriter Bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("island.txt",true))) {
        Bw.write("" + Island.habitats);
        Bw.newLine();
        Bw.write("" + Island.farms);
        Bw.newLine();
        Bw.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        

    }
}
```

Anyhelp will be appreciated

Comment: I tested it with plain strings, and for me, it was working and actually writing in both files. Could it be something wrong with accessing `Player.something`?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question and make the code a [mcve]? Maybe use a debugger iin your IDE or add debug `println`s to see what the code does? `saveIsland` swallows the exception, that is almost always a bad idea as you have no idea what is going wrong...

Comment: Maybe the files are in a location you are not expecting.

Comment: If you are doing this in Eclipse, a lot of times you won't see the files unless you refresh your project. Once you do that, you should be able to see the files.

Comment: @hfontanez yes it is in eclipse lemme refresh the project and check

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: @hfontanez not really, should i create a file in eclipse and name it player.txt? I have also tried naming it just player but nothind seems to work

Comment: @RogerLindsjö i have several packages and these txt files are in in the package with the class that this code is in.Should it be there or where the main class is

Comment: It should be at the project's root. At least that's how it worked for me. And the files are created automatically if they do not exist.

Comment: @AidHadzic Files don't need to be at the project's root. They can be anywhere. They can be in the package with the classes, or at the root, or at some folder in the project's path. Or they can even be in an external location to the project and even on a remote location. The location of the file could be dictated by a requirement or not specified at all; in which case, the developer can put the files anywhere. The location, however, will dictate the strategy used to access it.

Comment: @hfontanez I am referring to the code snippet that is posted in the question. When I was testing the code, I had already a project in which I created a simple class just to run this, and files were created in the project's root.

Comment: I have tracked the files to where they are stored on my machine and from there i see the data is being written. I don't understand why they don't show up in eclipse though, even when i restart it.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Instead of guessing and searching: provide a fully qualified file name,  e.g. "/home/louis/player.txt" so that you know exactly where it should appear